# How to use onSuggestionSelect, the abstract public method of SearchView.OnSuggestionListener?

Tags: java, android, callback, searchview

How do we use [onSuggestionSelect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnSuggestionListener.html#onSuggestionSelect(int)) in Android programming?

The other abstract public method onSuggestionClick is the usual one we need to use after the user clicks on the item from the suggestion list.

However, I am having a hard time trying to understand the use of onSuggestionSelect.

According to the [Official Android Developer Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnSuggestionListener.html#onSuggestionSelect(int)),

> onSuggestionSelect is called when a suggestion was selected by navigating to it
>
> onSuggestionClick (int position) is called when a suggestion was clicked.

I don't understand the term "when a suggestion was selected by **navigating** to it". How to do the navigating to it?

Answer (score -1):

The Android SearchView.OnSuggestionListener is used to Callback interface for selection events on suggestions. These callbacks are only relevant when a SearchableInfo has been specified.

Properties in the SearchableInfo are used to display labels, hints, suggestions, create intents for launching search results screens and controlling other affordances such as a voice button.

On suggestion select is called when you select one of your options in the Searchable info by navigating to it
boolean onSuggestionSelect (int position).

For examples on this have a look at http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.widget.SearchView.OnSuggestionListener